# Lyx: remove subsections from table of contents

Tags: lyx, table-of-contents

I don't want subsections to appear in the table of contents of my Lyx document. How do I turn them off? I went to Tools -> Settings -> Numbering & TOC, but it won't let me modify anything.

What should I do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I guess you mean `Document -> Settings… -> Numbering & TOC`, right? What do you mean by “It won't let you modify anything”? You can't move the slide (is that the right word?) above the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`? You would need to insert this as a LaTeX command via the `Insert-> TeX` menu, and I'm not entirely sure about the number, it might also be 1 or 3.

There is more information about document structure in LaTeX [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure).

Comment: I'd put it in the preamble (Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, that is a better idea.